# Django Rest Framework: Multiple branches of API w/ varying queryset/permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my Django-Rest-Framework application, I have the need to divide the API into two branches such as:

- `/api/public/...`
- `/api/private/...`

Consider a model `Analysis` like so:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Analysis(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

What I want then is:

- `/api/public/analysis` => filter queryset with `Q(public=True)`
- `/api/private/analysis` => filter queryset with `Q(user=request.user) | Q(public=False)`

Similar pattern is required in 5+ models.

I have thought of 2 half-baked solutions:

#### 1. `AbstractViewSet` sub-classed into `PublicViewSet` and `PrivateViewSet`

```py
class AbstractAnalysisViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Analysis.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnalysisSerializer
    ordering = [
        "-created_at",
    ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]

class PrivateAnalysisViewSet(AbstractAnalysisViewSet):
    def get_permissions(self):
        permissions = super(PrivateAnalysisViewSet, self).get_permissions()
        if self.action in ["retrieve"]:
            permissions.append(HasObjectPermission())
        return permissions

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PrivateAnalysisViewSet, self).get_queryset()
        if self.action in ["list"]:
            auth_user = self.request.user
            query = Q(user=auth_user) | Q(public=False)
            queryset = queryset.filter(query)
        return queryset

class PublicAnalysisViewSet(AbstractAnalysisViewSet):
    def get_permissions(self):
        permissions = super(PublicAnalysisViewSet, self).get_permissions()
        if self.action in ["retrieve"]:
            permissions.append(IsPublicObjectPermission())
        return permissions

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(AnalysisViewSet, self).get_queryset()
        if self.action in ["list"]:
            query = Q(public=True)
            queryset = queryset.filter(query)
        return queryset
```

This would work but I don't really want to duplicate views into multiple classes like that because then I also need to register multiple viewsets with the DRF `router`. As I said, I have to apply this same pattern in 5 models and that means 5*3=15 viewset classes which is hard to maintain over time and the number increases fast as my application grows in size.

#### 2. Determine `private` or `public` by parsing the `self.request.path`

```py
class AnalysisViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Analysis.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnalysisSerializer
    ordering = [
        "-created_at",
    ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]

    def get_permissions(self):
        permissions = super(PublicAnalysisViewSet, self).get_permissions()
        if self.action in ["retrieve"]:
            if "/private/" in self.request.path:
                permissions.append(HasObjectPermission())
            else:
                permissions.append(IsPublicObjectPermission())
        return permissions
```

I do like this approach **but I can't figure out how to register this viewset with the DRF `router`** such that it allows prefixing of `/public/` or `/private/`.

Any other cool ideas to solve this are welcome and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to register the path with the DRF router:

```py
from django.urls import re_path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import AnalysisViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r"analysis", AnalysisViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"(public|private)/", include(router.urls)),
]
```

**EDIT**:
For more verbosity and strictness:

> urls.py

```py
re_path(r"(?P<private_or_public_prefix>public|private)/", include(router.urls)),
```

> views.py

```py
    def get_permissions(self):
        permissions = super(PublicAnalysisViewSet, self).get_permissions()
        if self.action in ["retrieve"]:
            matcher = self.request.resolver_match
            if matcher.kwargs["private_or_public_prefix"] == "private":
                permissions.append(HasObjectPermission())
            else:
                permissions.append(IsPublicObjectPermission())
        return permissions
```

- [`HttpRequest.resolver_match` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match)